# Как js скрипту инициализироваться после зависимых dom компонентов

Tags: javascript, jquery, amd

### Есть:

- html где отображается какое-то сообщение
- js(1) скрипт который управляет этим сообщением
- другой js(2) который использует первый для подмены сообщения

```js
require.config({
  paths: {
    "jquery": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min"
  }
});

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  timerender.textContent = 'Задержка рендеринга элемента: ' + result + 'ms';
  return result;
}

//симуляция задержки
setTimeout(function() {
  wrap.innerHTML = "<div data-role='message'>Старое сообщение</div>";
}, getRandomInt(20, 40));

//script 1
define('message', ['jquery'], function($) {
  return {
    $el: $('[data-role=message]'),
    change: function(text) {
      this.$el.text(text);
    }
  };
});

//script 2       
require(['jquery', 'message'], function($, message) {
  message.change('Новое сообщение');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/rniemeyer/knockout-amd-helpers/master/ext/require/require.js"></script>
<div id='timerender'></div>
<div id='wrap'>
  <span>Функция не сработала</span>
</div>
```

Нужно несколько раз выполнить код (не меньше 10) что бы увидеть разные сообщения

### Проблема:

Все работает хорошо, но ненадежно, иногда `data-role=message` не успевает отрендериться, и второй скрипт пытается подменить сообщение, но так как дива еще нету, то ничего не происходит.

### Что нужно:

Не просто решить проблему, а понимать как лучше разруливать все подобные проблемы с зависимостью между скриптами.

### Какие варианты были отброшены

1. добавить в первый скрипт зависимость на `domReady`! — это приводит к тем же проблемам, но с другими скриптами, а поставить всем скриптам `domReady` долго и некрасиво со стороны пользователя
2. создать функцию инициализацию для первого скрипта, которые является единой точкой общения со скриптом, и можно притормозить скрипт до загрузки dom сообщения. В основном тут имеется введу использовать setTimeout(fun, 0)  — не подходит потому что, совсем не факт что перенос в конец очереди проверку успеет загрузиться dom элемент для первого компонента, и это не решает проблему в корне, а только один из симптомов, если применить эту же задержку сразу к двум компонентам то ситуация будет точно таже как и использовать domReady!
3. применить `promise` для свойства `$el` — это довольно запутанный вариант для такой простой задачи
4. обвернуть `$el` в функцию, то есть  `$el: function(){return $('[data-role=message]')}` — это решает проблему того, что при вызове первого скрипта в переменную `$el` записывается пустой jquery объект
5. использовать `jquery.ready` для всех зависимых dom элементов — более
   старый способ нежели `promise`, хотя если это бы внедрили в requryjs
   на уровень зависимостей...

Comment: Неужели такой сложный вопрос, что никто даже не пытался ответить?

Comment: Самый простой и надежный способ (DOMReady) вы исключили. Все остальное, IMHO, костыли.

Comment: как выглядит разметка? можете какой-нибудь jsfiddle показать?

Comment: как же я его добавлю в jsfiddle если тут нужно показывать взаимоотношение между как минимум двумя скриптами. И сама проблема воспроизводиться редко, а на некоторых машиннах вообще никогда, все зависит от того насколько в данный момент притомозил редеринг страницы. Если подскажите ресурс типа jsfiddle который сможет два файла js одновременно подгружать, то сделаю рабочий пример

Comment: Покажите как вы подключаете скприпт, и как "рендерится" `<div data-role='message'>Важный текст</div>`. Что мешает подключать скрипт после html ?

Comment: @duhon, например: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: @duhon, можете аргументировать, почему _варианты были отброшены_?

Comment: я обновил вопрос с возможностью увидеть ошибку, аргументы  я описал после тире. Могу подискусировать по каждому из отброшенных

Comment: @duhon, для второго варианта не привели аргументов :-) а для 4 указали что это решает проблему

Comment: @Grundy подправил, просто этот варинат, в более простой форме, мне предложили в ответе, и я там описал причину откидывания

Comment: @duhon, а что с 4 пунктом?

Comment: @Grundy это самый плохой вариант, по сути он решает только технический нюанс jquery, лично я думал что jquery обьект похож на elem.getElementsById тоесть возращает ссылку на поиск а не результат поиска. Но вот данный вариант не исправляет проблемы когда dom долго рендериться

Comment: Почему вариант 1 приводит к "тем же проблемам, но с другими скриптами"? Такого не должно быть.

Comment: но `elem.getElementsById` возвращает сам элемент

Comment: ой перепутал с getElementsByTagName и подобными которые возвращают ссылку на живую колекцию. :) очень редко пользуюсь нативным js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1

Вот способ отвязаться от элемента - но он подразумевает, что никто не обращается к $el напрямую (здесь и далее я подразумеваю, что элемент загружается вместе со страницей):

```
define('message', ['jquery'], function($) {
  var state = {
    text: "",
    change: function(text) {
      this.text = text
    }
  }

  $(function() {
    var oldState = state;
    state = {
      $el: $('[data-role=message]'),
      change: function (text) {
        $el.text(text)
      }
    }

    state.change(oldState.text)
  })

  return {
    change: function(text) {
      state.change(text)
    }
  }
})
```

Теперь модуль сохраняет текст у себя внутри до тех пор, пока dom не будет готов. Остальные модули могут сразу же вызывать метод `change` - а сообщение будет показано когда страница загрузится.

### 2

Получается слишком много кода? Тогда надо использовать примитивы более высокого уровня, вот к примеру:

```
define('message', ['jquery', 'knockout'], function($, ko) {
  var text = ko.observable();

  $(function() {
    var $el = $('[data-role=message]')

    ko.computed(function() {
      $el.text(text())
    })
  })

  return {
    change: function(text) {
      text(text)
    }
  }
})
```

Здесь я воспользовался функцией `computed` из библиотеки [`knockout.js`](http://knockoutjs.com/), которая создает значение, вычисляемое заново при любом изменении своих зависимостей. Тут оно, конечно, всегда равно `undefined` - но важно не это, а сам факт пере-вычисления, во время которого и обновляется элемент `$el`.

---

### 3

Если же надо отслеживать загрузку отдельных элементов - то вот модуль, который можно применить для этого:

```
define('sectionReady', function() {
  var sections = {}
  return {
    notify: function(name) {
      var q = sections[name]
      sections[name] = { push: function(onload) { onload() } }
      if (q instanceof Array) {
        for (var i=0; i<q.length; i++)
          q[i]()
      }
    },
    load: function(name, require, onload, config) {
      (sections[name] || (sections[name] = [])).push(onload)
    },
  }
})
```

Использование:

```
<div data-role='message'>Старое сообщение</div>
<script>require(['sectionReady'], function(s) { s.notify('message') })</script>

...

define('message', ['jquery', 'sectionReady!message'], function($) {
  return {
    $el: $('[data-role=message]'),
    change: function(text) {
      this.$el.text(text);
    }
  };
});
```

### 4

Разумеется, подходы можно комбинировать:

```
define('message', ['require'], function(require) {
  var state = {
    text: "",
    change: function(text) {
      this.text = text
    }
  }

  (require)(['jquery', 'sectionReady!message'], function($) {
    var oldState = state;
    state = {
      $el: $('[data-role=message]'),
      change: function (text) {
        $el.text(text)
      }
    }

    state.change(oldState.text)
  })

  return {
    change: function(text) {
      state.change(text)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: да это решает проблему set, но не решает проблему get. Подумаю как можно обыграть get. Сейчас вижу решение get-a это выбор между вернуть пустоту либо подождать элемент

Comment: @duhon - get в смысле "получить элемент" или "получить текст сообщения"? Если первое - то тут только переносить *всю* работу с элементом один в модуль, иначе задача решения не имеет. Если речь идет о "получить сообщение" - то во всех предложенных мною вариантах сообщение хранится и его есть откуда достать.

Comment: "получить текст", храниться текст, но до момента рендера элемента храниться только дефолтная пустата. Кстате что я не так сделал http://jsfiddle.net/aub203d6/17/ у меня все также неработает

Comment: @duhon писать `notify('message')` надо не в случайном месте, а в том, где создается элемент, в том-то и смысл! Вот исправленная версия: http://jsfiddle.net/aub203d6/18/

Comment: @duhoh мои примеры 1, 2 и 4 хранят текст сообщения отдельно от элемента, и его можно оттуда достать даже если элемент еще не загружен.

Comment: хм, так в примере я создал функцию setTimeout только для симуляции задержки рендеринга, но мысль я вроде уловил, повесть domReady! на отдельный компонент который дождеться нужный мне элемент и пушнит в реестр уведомление

Comment: @duhon видимо, не уловили. Вы же сами писали, что вам нельзя использовать `domReady!` - и тут же сами предлагаете так сделать! Какая разница, через сколько посредников вы будете ждать `domReady`?

Comment: @duhon если элемент задан на странице статически - то надо включить скрипт, вызывающий `notify`, сразу после него. В таком случае браузер выполнит этот скрипт как только загрузит ваш элемент. Элемент к этому моменту не обязательно будет показан пользователю - но будет гарантированно существовать в DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй перенести код из второго скрипта в конец потока исполнения, обернув его в `setTimeout`

должно быть что-то вроде такого

```
requre(['jquery', 'control/message'], function ($, message) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if ($('#error').length) {
            message.hide()
        }
    }, 0);
}
```

И кстати jsfiddle умеет подгружать хоть дюжину сторонних скриптов, в закладке "External Resources" надо просто ввести их урлы

Comment: этот вариант я тоже хотел, но отбросил его быстрей других, по двум причинам: 

1) совсем не факт что пенеся в конец очереди проверку успеет загрузиться dom элемент для первого компонента
2) это не решает проблему в корне, а только один из симптомов, если применить эту же задержку сразу к двум компонентам то ситуация будет точно буже, и проще тогда использовать domReady!

Comment: Но это же костыль в чистом виде. Который к тому же придется дублировать по всей программе...

Comment: ДОМ элемент успеет загрузиться, если скрипт будет подключен в конце body, после всей разметки. 

Так что, в целом, достаточно просто перенести точку входа в скрипты (т.к. это реквайр, то очевидно что точка входа - это подключение реквайра) в самый конец страницы.

Comment: а чем отличается перенести точку входа в самый конец страницы, и поставить всем скриптам domReady! ?

Comment: @duhon смотря какой domReady ты имеешь в виду. Например $.ready() - это синтетическое событие. Изначально джейквери пытается использовать нативное событие DOMContentLoaded, если его нет (старый ИЕ например) - тогда используется load событие на window. window.onload - это не очень хорошо, т.к. вызывается только после того, как браузер распарсит html, построит из него DOM и загрузит картинки. DOMContentLoaded вызывается сразу после того как готова ДОМ структура, не ожидая догрузки картинок.

Comment: Перенос же скрипта в конец body гарантировано запустит выполнение скриптов после построения ДОМ структуры без ожидания догрузки картинок (т.к. браузер будет парсить и выполнять весь документ вместе со скриптами в один поток синхронно).

Ну и в реализации это самый простой и надежный способ, тем более в твоем случае.

Comment: я имел введу плагин requrejs:domReady, но логика таже что и $.redy(). Перенос requrejs в конец загрузки страницы, мы чуть поможем доисторическим браузерам, но замедлим все скрипты на порядок, так как попросим всем подождать dom. Для моего маленького примера это оправданно, точно также как и использовать requrejs:domReady, это приведет к проблемам которые я описал в вопросе.

Comment: Объективно не вижу причин по которым все скрипты будут замедлены на порядок. Можно на живом примере?

Answer (score 1):

Если элемент, от которого вы зависите, задан на странице в статическом виде - достаточно прописать среди зависимостей `domReady!`.

Так, в вашем примере, достаточно добавить `domReady!` в список зависимостей `message`. Второму скрипту добавлять `domReady!` в список зависимостей не требуется - ведь он уже зависит от `message`, который зависит от `domReady!`.

Если же элемент рендерится динамически - то надо что-нибудь делать с тем модулем, который его рендерит. Например, возвращать промиз, который будет разрешен после окончания рендеринга, и испрользовать в модуле `message` зависимость, использующую плагины [`rq`](https://github.com/asengupta/requirejs-q), [`promise`](https://github.com/jokeyrhyme/requirejs-promise) или [`promiseme`](https://github.com/andreineculau/requirejs-promiseme)

Comment: domReady! приводит к проблеме зависимостей из за очереди загрузки скриптов. Реально это воспроизвелось на прокте, представим что у нас не 2 скрипта а 25, и первыми загружаються очень важные скрипты на которые все зависят. Если добавить к первым скриптам domRedy! то половина скриптом начнет долго ждать загрузки dom (пользователь абалдевает от деграний страницы, что то гдето налету исчезает, скролиться и тд.), а остальные которые имеют косвенную связь начнут падать (например они не знали что нужный им dom элемент создаеться какимто скриптом)

Comment: @duhon но если вы в скрипте, прямо или косвенно, завязаны на html-элемент - вам в любом случае придется дождаться его загрузки! И в любом случае все начнет дергаться и скроллиться! Если вам хочется этого избежать - надо как-то рвать зависимость от конкретного html-элемента, по-другому и не получится.

Comment: поэтому я хочу что бы компоненты зависили от других компонентов и от конкретных dom элементов, а не от всего dom-a. Сейчас я вижу что это грамотно решает promise, но нужно все компоненты переучить работать друг с другом, а это на примере 25 скриптов (тут смайлик ужаса), это тоже самое что проект переписать с синхронного на асинхронный вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Пример с использованием Promise. не думаю что очень сложно, но не так красиво как хотелось :-)

```js
require.config({
  paths: {
    "jquery": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min"
  }
});

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  timerender.textContent = 'Задержка рендеринга элемента: ' + result + 'ms';
  return result;
}

//симуляция задержки
setTimeout(function() {
  wrap.innerHTML = "<div data-role='message'>Старое сообщение</div>";
}, getRandomInt(20, 40));

//script 1
define('message', ['jquery'], function($) {
  return {
    $el_p: new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      function checker() {
        var element = $('[data-role="message"]');
        if (element.length > 0) resolve(element);
        else setTimeout(checker, 200);
      }
      checker();
    }),

    change: function change(text) {
      if (!this.$el) {
        this.$el_p.then(function(element) {
          this.$el = element.text(text);
        }.bind(this));

      } else {
        this.$el.text(text);
      }
    }
  };
});

//script 2       
require(['jquery', 'message'], function($, message) {
  message.change('Новое сообщение');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/rniemeyer/knockout-amd-helpers/master/ext/require/require.js"></script>
<div id='timerender'></div>
<div id='wrap'>
  <span>Функция не сработала</span>
</div>
```

Comment: проблема будет когда мы в третьем скрипте захотим узнать текст сообщения, тоесть в первом скрипте добавиться метод getText. Если у нас элемент еще не отрендерился то мы вынуждены будем вернуть либо промис (а третий скрипт думаю ждет текст), либо пустоту (а третий скрипт возможно выполнит кучу всего лишнего получив фейковый данные)

Comment: @duhon, если везде использовать Promise - не сохраняя результат как я сделал - такой проблемы не будет. Просто везде будет обращение в  функции then от Promise

Answer (score 0):

А прописать зависимость скриптов через shim не подойдет? как минимум один будет грузиться после другого.

Выполнение рендера отслеживать по кастомному event'у и ловить это событие во втором скрипте.

Зависимость задаётся один раз в конфиге, генерация события - ничтожное дополнение в коде.

Прослушка события - это можно сделать фабричным методом, который будет доступен для всех, ну или (если исп-ся extend) для тех, кто унаследовался от нужного объекта.

Comment: звучит интересно (правда я не все понял), немогли бы взять мой пример и добавить туда описанные вами вещи, на практике хочу посмотреть

Comment: да, могу, набросаю и скину. Правда кто-то минусит, а объяснения не пишет, может это и неправильный аппроач

Comment: @Mr.Brightside, _аппроач_ => подход :-)

Comment: через shim нельзя сделать ничего такого, чего нельзя было бы сделать без него. Это всего-лишь настройка оберток над старыми модулями, нет никакого смысла использовать shim для *своих* модулей.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать библиотеку https://github.com/paragmajum/bornReady и друге подобные которые позволяют слушать браузерный евент animationstart

```js
//Технический часть - сейчас неважна
require.config({
  paths: {
    "jquery": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min"
  }
});

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  timerender.textContent = 'Задержка рендеринга элемента: ' + result + 'ms';
  return result;
}

//Компонент отвечающий за ожидания конкретного элемента с атрибутом data-ready
define('sectionReady', function() {
  return {
    load: function(name, require, onload, config) {
      var sel = "[data-ready='" + name + "']";
      bornReady(sel, function() {
        onload(this);
      })
    },
  }
});

//Симуляция задержки рендера
setTimeout(function() {
  wrap.innerHTML = "<div data-ready='message'>Старое сообщение</div>";
}, getRandomInt(20, 40));

//script 1
define('message', ['jquery', 'sectionReady!message'], function($, message) {
  return {
    $el: $(message),
    set: function(text) {
      this.$el.text(text);
    },
    get: function() {
      this.$el.text();
    }
  };
});

//script 2       
require(['jquery', 'message'], function($, message) {
  message.set('Новое сообщение');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/rniemeyer/knockout-amd-helpers/master/ext/require/require.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/paragmajum/bornReady/master/js/bornReady.js"></script>
<div id='timerender'></div>
<div id='wrap'>
  <span>Функция не сработала</span>
</div>
```

В данном примере скрипт который зависит от dom элемента нужно прописать зависимость `'sectionReady!message'` где message это html элемент с атрибутом `data-ready='message'`. Приятный бонус в том что нам не важно откуда появиться этот элемент, придет с сервера или динамически создаться другим компонентом. А минусов в том что это временный костыль, не всеми браузерами поддерживаться и добавляет лишнее торможение для системы в целом